# .Net SAML how to logout with expired token

Tags: .net, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am working a .net project that is integrated with SAML sso, and package [itfoxtect](https://www.itfoxtec.com/IdentitySaml2). On successful login, A session cookie will be created for this new session. Everything is working fine. However, the token issued by the IdP has a lifetime of 1 hour, so after logging in for 1 hour, the logout will lead to an error since the name id from claim identity is gone. My question is that is there any standard to way logout directly? or refresh the token lifetime and then logout?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the sliding expiration to prolong the application session as long as the user is active. Then the ITfoxtec Identity SAML 2.0 component has access to the session information and can do logout.

```
services.AddSaml2(slidingExpiration: true);
```

Link to sample where the slidingExpiration is enabled.
https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Startup.cs#L58